# Painting edges of a 2x2 grid with 4 colours

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, graph-theory

Can you paint the edges of a 2x2 grid with 4 colours, such that:

- The colours of edges of every 1x1 square are different.
- The colours of edges adjacent to every vertex are different.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Is this what is meant?

Looks trivial though...

Comment: Correct and well done! Now you can try the harder version of this puzzle: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89880/painting-edges-of-a-3x3-grid-with-4-colours