# Painting edges of a 3x3 grid with 4 colours

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, graph-theory

Can you paint the edges of a 3x3 grid with 4 colours, such that:

- The colours of edges of every 1x1 square are different.
- The colours of edges adjacent to every vertex are different.

Here is a similar puzzle for a 2x2 grid: [Painting edges of a 2x2 grid with 4 colours](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89878/painting-edges-of-a-2x2-grid-with-4-colours)

Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that

> I can, as follows:
>
> ```
> @ -1- @ -4- @ -1- @
> |     |     |     |
> 2     3     2     3
> |     |     |     |
> @ -4- @ -1- @ -4- @
> |     |     |     |
> 3     2     3     2
> |     |     |     |
> @ -1- @ -4- @ -1- @
> |     |     |     |
> 2     3     2     3
> |     |     |     |
> @ -4- @ -1- @ -4- @
> ```

I further remark that

> this pattern can be continued indefinitely, so it's no harder for (say) a 15x15 square.

Comment: That's a better answer than mine, I'd say! But it would be interesting to ask for the total number of different solutions on an $n\times n$ grid.

Comment: Great find Gareth! Indeed it seems you can just use this pattern for larger grids.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky: It also extends to three dimensions, where you colour the faces shared between the cubical cells using 6 colours, no cell has two faces of the same colour, and no two faces of the same colour share an edge.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Again got it on the first try...

Comment: Ah... this time a bit late ^_^